# YouTube Data API - How to retrieve video id at the start of uploading

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use YouTube Data API v3 to upload videos from my web application. I have decided to use resumable upload method in order to deal with network failures, besides my video files are large.

However,  (if I have understand well) resumable upload is not capable to resume the uploading when my application goes down.

Therefore I am thinking about to store video id in my app database, at the start of uploading. So if my app goes down during uploading, I will be able to retrieve the uploaded video status.

So I have two questions:

1. It is possible to retrieve the video id at the start of uploading? YouTube assign an id to video as soon as uploading start. However I was able to retrieved when upload completed
2. If it is not a way to retrieve the video id at the start of uploading, how could I deal with a failure of my application during uploading?
   Thanks a lot!
   John

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now there is a way to do it. You should look for "X-Goog-Correlation-Id" in the response header for the video id.

Documentation will be updated shortly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is possible to get this video id using the api client library?

Comment: I have NO idea how this answer is not accepted. This literally saved me hours (of course I lost hours before finding this answer, but that's beside the point). Thank you so much Ibrahim, I was using the documentation found here:  -- I wish the docs mentioned this header, as I was doing a search query, after starting the resumable upload to track down my video id. Which was so ugly, as it required a sleep to work (presumably for Google's cache's to clear)